# classes that can only be instantiated with the using keyword

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop, .net-4.8

I'm new to C# and .Net platforms. I have a problem.

I want to create a custom class. This class has `Dispose` method and implements the `IDisposable` interface. And I want to force everyone who wants to use my class and create an instance to use `using` syntax.

Because I want to it

```
using (Person person = new Person()) 
{
    // Some code example
}
```

I don't want to allow creation of an instance without `using` declarations

```
Person person = new Person () // I don't want it this method
```

Is it possible or not? (maybe a custom attribute, maybe .net attributes, maybe another method)

What do you? What advice would you give me about this job?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible

Comment: You could use some Analyzer like https://www.nuget.org/packages/IDisposableAnalyzers to warn the consumer of the class that they should be handling idisposable correctly

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The IDisposable interface is mainly used for classes that use unsafe/unmanaged code, such as wrapping C++ methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: This answer applies to SDK-style projects only.)

It is possible to get Code Analysis to [show an error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000) for certain cases where a disposable object is not disposed.

For example, consider the following code:

```
static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        test();
    }

    static void test()
    {
        var file = File.Open("test", FileMode.Open); // Error!
        Console.WriteLine(file.Length);
    }
}
```

With the right Code Analysis rule, the line marked "// Error!" will cause the following compile error:

```
Error   CA2000  Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object created by
'File.Open("test", FileMode.Open)'
before all references to it are out of scope
```

The error will not be provoked if the disposable object is passed into or out of the method that's using it, because it is then assumed that other code will be responsible for disposing it.

To add code analysis to an SDK-style project to demonstrate this:

Add the following ruleset file to the project folder. Call it "WarnIfUndisposed.ruleset":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="WarnIfUndisposed" Description="Warn if object is not disposed" ToolsVersion="17.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers">
    <Rule Id="CA2000" Action="Error" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

I've deliberately only included the specific error that we want in this ruleset, just for demonstration purposes. A real ruleset would of course have many other warning and errors enabled.

Having added that to the project, add the "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" NuGet package to the project. After doing that, something like this should be in the project file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="6.0.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

(Actual version number may differ.)

Finally add the following to the project file in a `<PropertyGroup>` section:

```
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>WarnIfUndisposed.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

Unload and reload the project (if necessary) and rebuild. You should now see an error for certain cases where you forget to dispose a disposable object.

This is just a quick and dirty demo to show that an error can be provoked. ".ruleset" files are not the latest format.

For more details, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview

Comment: thanks for giving advice sir. And I have a another problem.  Will this process appear during code writing or only during compilation? i want something to appear when i write code.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible that you want to delay calling `Dispose` beyond a using statement:

```
void Func()
{
   var thingToDispose = new DisposableThing();
   DisposeMyThing(thingToDispose)
}

void DisposeMyThing(IDisposable disposable)
{
   disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Therefore you cannot do this with just implementing `IDisposable`.

I believe your original requirement is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas you cannot restrict this, you can always implement the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#implement-the-dispose-pattern) to make sure that the GC finalizes your object even if it was not instantiated in a `using` construct or was not disposed explicitly. (Edit: *"to make sure"* is somewhat incorrect: finalizers are called only when there are no references pointing to your object anymore and might be executed with a considerable delay, depending on how many GC generations the object survived and a few other things).

As you didn't provide any details about your `Person` class we cannot really tell whether a finalizer (C# destructor) is needed in your case so unless you have unmanaged resources there is some chance you don't really need it:

```cs
public class Person : IDisposable
{
    bool _isDisposed;

    // This is called at the and of using or by explicit disposal
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // so GC will not call the finalizer
    }

    // This is called by the GC if this instance was not disposed.
    // A typical Person class probably does not need this though.
    ~Person() => Dispose(false);

    // The disposing parameter is true from Dispose, false from the finalizer.
    // This method can be private and non-virtual if the class is sealed.
    // Derived classes can just override this method for additional logic.
    protected virtual void Dispose(disposing bool)
    {
         if (_isDisposed)
             return;

         if (disposing)
         {
             // dispose your other disposable fields here
         }

         // free your unmanaged resources here or do whatever
         // else that must be executed when the instance is released
         _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```